# How to mount a bootable APFS snapshot from command line?

Tags: command-line, time-machine, mount, apfs

First, I have Time Machine enabled and my aim is to make `rclone` cloud backups of a snapshot of all locally backed up files, excluding system files.  It is mainly non-system volumes and `$HOME`.  I am able to mount non-bootable snapshots from the command line.  So far, haven't been able to mount bootable ones.  This is on macOS 14.1.2.  Apple Silicon, but that likely doesn't matter.

I start with this to make a snapshot:

```bash
$ tmutil snapshot
```

and the response is:

```bash
NOTE: local snapshots are considered purgeable and may be removed at any time by deleted(8).
Created local snapshot with date: 2023-12-06-202527
```

Then, I find the snapshots just made:

```bash
$ diskutil apfs listSnapshots /Volumes/me |grep Name: |tail -1
    Name:        com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-12-06-202527.local
$
```

I can mount this:

```bash
mount_apfs -o ro -s com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-12-06-202527.local /Volumes/me ~/tmp/snapshot
```

All fine.  However, when I try to do this for the `/` snapshot
I get a snapshot name of
`com.apple.os.update-E071D10CC651CAA7FA82B6ABD01FB1E761A267F6EA0104F2743F887F5B4BCC8C` and

```bash
$ sudo mount_apfs -o ro -s com.apple.os.update-E071D10CC651CAA7FA82B6ABD01FB1E761A267F6EA0104F2743F887F5B4BCC8C / ~/tmp/snapshot
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Resource busy
$
```

I can use the GUI for `diskutil` and mount the same `/` snapshot and I get an interesting warning:

[image]

This is why I tried `sudo` for the `mount_apfs` command above for the failing case.  I tried it without and it does the same thing.  I also tried varying the mount location from `~/tmp/snapshot` to `/tmp/snapshot`, etc.  Nothing worked.

Comment: Just in case you're not aware, since macOS Catalina, system files are stored on a seperate volume of the disk. This went a step further in macOS Big Sur with the introduction of Signed System Volumes (SSV). Read up about SSV, because making changes to the System Volume requires jumping through multiple hoops to disable the authenticated root, mounting the system volume, making the changes and then creating a snapshot and blessing the changes. Be careful, because if you haven't done the correct steps, macOS won't be able to boot up.

Comment: It's the non-system files I'm interested in.  Really just `/Users/$USER`.  I can mount the snapshot using the GUI and use `rclone` on it fine.  This entire thing is just about doing it automatically via the command line.